Population density ignoring or adjusting for e.g. mountainous areas
Population density is a metric often quoted, however it seems to me not always a useful tool.
The Netherlands for example, has few hills, or in general, gradients, and so most of the country can be built on (of course, they reclaimed some of it, and they could reclaim more!).
Contrast this with Hong Kong, which has got quite a few hills/peaks (compared to something like the Netherlands! They ain't no Mount Everest, but a lot higher than the high point of South Holland of 37m).
I tried to find, but failed, to find a population density measure disregarding, or discounting, mountainous areas or other relevant geographic factors?

It might be hard to define.  Switzerland has significant populations even in its mountainous parts, but do cities on the valley floor of the Rhone Valley count as living in a mountainous area or not?

@gerrit I agree it's hard to define, but I also think it is a very interesting question, so I was hoping others have tried before.

Disregarding lakes an rivers may be more interesting. Some statistics has also Inhabitable area, but I do not think there is something general. -- I would take precise density area, crossing with bioclimatic zones, and "count", so you can select yourself what you will not consider habitable. (note: altitude is not enough, so the climatic or bioregions): on North lower mountain may not be habitable, but on south you can get large cities at 4000m (13,000ft), e.g. La Paz.
